# Multipeer Connectivity Resource Type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, multipeer-connectivity

I want to send some files from my Documents folder to other Peers. For Text and Image files sendResourceAtURL works perfect. But when i send Audio or Movie Files i get an Error: Unsupported resource type. Is there a list of supported Files? I can not found any list in the documentary. Thanks for Help!

```
NSString* dataPath = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"];

for (int i = 0; i < documentsArray.count; i++) {
    NSString* filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"file:///private%@/%@", dataPath,[documentsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
    NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:filePath];
    NSLog(@"FilePath: %@", filePath);
    for (int p = 0; p < [appdelegate.mpcController.session connectedPeers].count;p++)
    {
        NSLog(@"Datei %@ an Peer %@", [documentsArray objectAtIndex:i], [[appdelegate.mpcController.session connectedPeers] objectAtIndex:p]);
        progress = [appdelegate.mpcController.session sendResourceAtURL:url withName:[documentsArray objectAtIndex:i] toPeer: [[appdelegate.mpcController.session connectedPeers] objectAtIndex:p] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"Error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }}];
        NSLog(@"Progress: %@",progress.description);
    }

}
```

In documentsArray are Strings with the Name of the Files with different types. For Images and Texts works fine.

Comment: Post what you have tried. SO is a coding help website, and it's hard to help you with your code if you don't provide any.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the image/audio URLs you are using actually work? For example, can you init an `AVURLAsset` with them?